# What is benefit when convert signed 16 bit to unsigned 8 bit in medical image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an DICOM image with its type is 16 bit signed. I see some paper, the author often converts it to unsigned 8 bit. But they did not explain why they do it. Could you explain what is benefit of this work? And How to implement it by matlab code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsigned 8-bit images take up less memory, and some operations, for example median filtering, can be performed much faster on them.

However, you risk losing information when the dynamic range of the original image spans more than 256 grayvalues.

If you do want to convert images, you can perform `convertedImage = uint8(image - min(image(:)));`, but if you are not limited in terms of RAM, you may want to convert the image to double instead `convertedImage = double(image)`, since that way, more mathematical operations, such as many filtering approaches, will be available to you.

Comment: in the case of converting to uint8, one can use uint8(mat2gray(image, [0 255])), as opposed to subtracting the image from the min which may cause some over saturation of the image, as high values may be clipped to 255.

Comment: correction: normalizing the image to 0 to 255 should be: uint8(mat2gray(image,[min(image(:)) max(image(:))]).*255)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is, it makes the image take less memory. This not only helps when it comes to preserving storage space but also will most probably speed up processing times.
Also an algorithm which works on uint8 has a good chance of working for other types, too.

to convert from int32 to uint8 in matlab you have to consider what exactly you want:

does your image contain only values which span only 256 values? then you can do `convertedImage = uint8(image - min(image(:)))` like jonas said, but this will clip your values are out of range:

```
>> uint8([-1 0 1 200 255 256 257])

ans =

    0    0    1  200  255  255  255

>> uint8([-1 0 1 200 255 256 257] - min([-1 0 1 200 255 256 257]))

ans =

    0    1    2  201  255  255  255
```

if your image uses the full span of possible int16 vals you will want to scale it first so its values range from 0 to 256.